# what host to set for RabbitMQ send test

Tags: rabbitmq

So I am having trouble understanding how to use rabbitmq. I have the following Send.java class I am using RabbitMQ to send a message:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Send {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException {
        // create a connection to the server
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("WHAT DO I PUT HERE"); // <==========================What do I put here??
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        // next we create a channel, which is where most of the API
        // for getting things done resides
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        // to send we must declare a queue for us to send to; then
        // we can publish a message to the queue:
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        String message = "Hello World!";
        channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");

        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

I don't really understand what I can set the host as to make this run as a Java application. Can someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: You set it to the host that your rabbitMQ server is running on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really self-explanatory... This method sets the default host to use for connection.
If you're using RabbitMQ on your local machine you can set it like this:

```
factory.setHost("localhost");
```

Or alternatively:

```
factory.setHost("127.0.0.1");
```